# Should TDD be applied at initial prototype stage?

Tags: tdd

I have a question about applying tdd on early stages of development. Frequently, when starting developing a project, the client does not know exactly what the precise requirements are and consequently changes them after seeing the first prototypes. If we apply tdd from the very beginnning of the project, it turns out that a big portion of our tests (acceptance, integration, unit) will be soon either deleted or updated. Is this normal? If not, how to proceed at this initial phase of product development?

Comment: Don't TDD prototypes. Use them (or paper/UI mockups) to learn quick-and-dirty. Once you are 80% certain that there won't be major changes.. throw away the prototype + do it again this time with TDD

Comment: Also you find too much thrashing in the requirements once stories are marked done, it might be a bigger problem.. inspect your customer - product owner - tester triad

Answer (score 3):

I will comfort you, Markus: it is normal that clients change their minds at the beginning. The funny thing is that, even with time, the only thing they don't change their minds about is changing their minds about stuff all the time.

So do not be worried that some portion of your tests will go to the bin along with the implementation because it will be the same in later stages. What you can do as a developer/BA/whatever is to try and point them in the right direction as soon as possible, discuss things with them so you don't develop too much "useless" stuff.

Especially if you're working in a very agile fashion the requirements might change from iteration to iteration, this by no means should make you think that tests are useless at any stage of the project.

Also it is very normal for tests to get updated when the requirements change. People need to start taking tests more seriously (it is srs business, k?!) and realize that it is something that: a) is there not just to annoy you, b) should evolve with the project because it will most probably save you a lot of trouble.

Prototypes suggested by Yishai are a good solution. Sometimes. BUT you really need to watch out. In a lot of situations when a client sees a prototype he likes/is very similar to what he wants he will think "wow you're almost already done! when can we launch it?"? And then it is really hard to explain them that it is only a prototype and that you need to start from scratch. In many cases people just start using the prototype as the main project and they do not feel like adding missing tests or improving the existing codebase. That is almost how the application I am currently working with got created (10+ years now!).

Comment: Yes, a very common result with a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal.

Another option, though is you can build true prototypes to get some feedback to nail down some technical architecture questions that can't be changed later, and build them without tests. The requirement is, though, that those prototypes be literally deleted when the real project work is underway (they may stay around initially to look at how some things were done, etc. but not a drop of code is left in the final product).

You should also be sure you are writing acceptance tests that represent functionality the user actually wants, not just artifacts you happen to build. It seems odd that a lot of acceptance tests would get thrown out. They may need to get updated, to represent new requirements, but they should, in general, be quite accurate, as not that much should change, if you do the most important things first.

But sometimes they truly don't know what they want, or what the technology is capable of, so things can change radically. Those are high risk/high cost projects no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Things always change, if anything unit tests will help you clarify requirements earlier. Integration tests can probably come a bit later but unless your prototypes are throw away I'd try write unit tests from the start. Like anything there are compromises but writing tests sooner rather than later helps. changing tests when requirements change will help validate those changes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zenzen - showing a client a working prototype earns a puzzled, suspicious look when you state it needs re-writing.

And like Yishai, i believe in making *disposable* prototypes first as putting a visual mock-up in front of the client reveals so much about what they actually want (most haven't got a clue until you show them)..

However, this visual prototype inspires a whole world of new thoughts in the client so, inevitably, requirements change..

So, my method:

- Keep the prototype as simple and static a mock-up as possible (No TDD).
- The moment i'm asked to demonstrate real-world functionality, I consider this the beginning (Full TDD).